# Editing Account Detail for a user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

```
$query = " UPDATE Users SET username = " 
  . $username 
  . "AND password =" 
  . $password 
  . "AND email =" 
  . $email 
  . " WHERE id = '$id'";
```

im putting this query into my database sql window and i get this message

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$query = " UPDATE Users SET username = " . $username . "AND password =" . $passw' at line 1
```

can anyone help

Comment: You should consider using prepare-statements if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Mysql Update query does not work the way you are trying it should be

```
$query = "UPDATE 
Users 
SET username = '$username',
password ='$password',
email ='$email'
WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Need to have single quote for the string values and also updated columns needs to be separated by comma.

Also you need to start using mysqli or PDO with prepared statement.

Comment: This is all quite true, but I believe that the crux of the problem is "im putting this query into my database sql window". Double check the error message provided ;)

Answer (score 1):

you need quotes , replace `and` with `,`:

```
$query = " UPDATE Users SET username = '" . $username . "' , password = '" . $password . "' , email = '" . $email . "' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

however consider `injection` issues

Answer (score 0):

Please consider moving on to `Mysqli` and also your code is vulnerable to injections.

As of your question

```
$query = " UPDATE Users SET username = '$username' AND password ='$password' AND email ='$email' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Enclose values in `'`   quotes

```
$query = "UPDATE Users 
          SET username = "'.$username.'" ,password="'.$password.'" ,email ="'. $email.'"
          WHERE id = '$id'"; /* note enclosing single quotes above */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "UPDATE Users SET username='$username', password='$password', email='$email' WHERE id='$id'";
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers bring up very valid points, but the real issue (the actual thing causing the error provided) seems to be that you are putting a PHP statement directly into an SQL interpreter. SQL/MySQL is not going to parse PHP for you. You need to run that command in a PHP environment.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like its a syntax error. Try replacing the double quotes with single quotes and dots with +

$query = ' UPDATE Users SET username = ' +$username + 'AND password = ' + $password + 'AND email = ' + $email + ' WHERE id = ' + $id;

If $id is a varchar enclose with single quotes again.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that the OP is incorrectly trying to run a PHP command in an SQL interpreter, please do not answer a question tagged as `PHP` if you do not understand the basic language operators of PHP. `+` is not used for concatenation.

Comment: The statement "Im putting this query into my database sql window and i get this message" made me think he was trying to convert the query to a sql query.